# How to apply validation using VBA on dynamic cells in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA, I am having problems creating a simple VBA script. One of the cell is static but one cell is dynamic. that is why i have applied validation using a script. The script simply looks for the cell Date1 and Date2. Then gets cells on their right side. Then it compares those two cells and throws a validation error if Date1>Date2.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Date1 As Range
    Dim Date2 As Range
    
    ->Set Date1 = Sheets("Data").Columns("B1:B150").Find(What:="Date1", LookIn:=xlValues)

    Set Date2 = Sheets("Data").Columns("B1:B150").Find(What:="Date2", LookIn:=xlValues)


    If Date1.Offset(0, 1).Value < Date2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        ' Display a message if the validation condition is not met
        MsgBox "Date1 cannot be before than Date2.", vbExclamation, "Validation Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

It throws error "Application defined or Object Defined" error on given line.

I have tried multiple methods but failed. Please guide on how to make this script run fine.

Another problem is that this script runs everytime a cell is changed. so it will always give validation error on all cells changed until we change Date1 and Date2. Please also guide on how to only run script when we change Date1 or Date2 cells. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of trying "multiple methods" it would be good to **clearly describe what you try doing**. **In words**... Only looking to a not working piece of code (you say that) we cannot understand too much... 1. Do you want processing cells changed in the range you show in your code ("B1:B150"). Supposing that `Sheets("Data")` is the one where the event exists, would be a correct assumption? 2. Do you want comparing the changed cell with the one from one column to the right, independent of the row? If not, please clearly explain (in similar terms) what you need.

Comment: Usually, an event code does not have too much meaning if you do not use its `Target` parameter...

Comment: @FaneDuru I have a cell named Date1 and to the right of this cell is another cell with the Date value. similarly I have another cell named Date2 and to the right of it is its date. I want to compare both dates and if one is greater than the other then throw validation error. Since one of the dates is dynamic, I selected Date1 cell to its left. because both Date1 and its value can be is some other cell in the same row. That is what i am trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: I still cannot understand anything... Why do you use the `Change` event? Do you need/want it being triggered **if any cell in the respective sheet is changed**? What "I have a cell named Date1" does mean? Where do you have it? Anywhere in the respective sheet? Based on what to identify it? Do you want the event being triggered **only when this Date1 (you have) is changed**, or if any other cell will be changed? Based on **what logic `Date2` to be found** relative to `Date1`? Should `Date2` be in a specific range/area (column, row etc.) and also trigger the event if it is changed?

Comment: @FaneDuru I have solved the problem using the answers. Thankyou for your kind reply.

Comment: If you would carefully read what I wrote/asked about, you probably will understand that your event code wastes Excel resources in most cases when it is triggered. Even if in the respective sheet there are only those four involved cells... If you only need to not have an error anymore, you solved the problem, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Columns property incorrectly; it doesn't accept a range expression. Either use `Columns(2)` to represent the B column, or `Range("B1:B150")`.

To make your code more robust, check the result of the Find expression before using it to do anything (check for `Date1 is Nothing` and for `Date2 is Nothing` before referring to them).

Answer (score 1):

For only running this code when those cells have changed see [Application.Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect)

You are probably getting the error because the Find is failing. Try using named ranges instead